# Can ViewModel class conforms to UITableviewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource in iOS as per MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I have a viewcontroller which displays a table view with complex UI and different type of data depending on certain conditions/usertype. This involves logic to segregate and process data on user selection and hide/unhide expand/close section. As I am using MVVM pattern, can my viewmodel class conform to UITableviewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, so that I have a thinner viewcontroller?

Something like -

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

 .
 .

  let viewModel = HomeViewModel()

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

 .
 .

  tableView.delegate = viewModel
  tableView.dataSource = viewModel
}

class HomeViewModel: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

//Implement delegates

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, set any object that conforms to those protocols as the delegate, data source or separate them to different objects, anything and anyone can implement a protocol.

When writing a complex table view data source or delegate, It’s better to define a type whose purpose is to be a table view’s data source. This helps to better separate responsibilities between objects.

You can find an example by Apple implementing different objects as the table/collection View's data source here:
[Advanced User Interfaces with Collection Views by apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/232/)

These object/s doesn't have to be your viewModel, but please see a good example when it is:
[MVVM with viewModel as the table datasource](https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-multiple-cell-types-2df91a206429)

Comment: Thanks.. Found example really relevant

Comment: @ManjunathK
Great!
Happy it's useful, it has more info then the question and I really learned from it

Comment: Do you think by any chance we violate Apple standards by setting viewmodel as the delegate for tableview? Can I see few more examples any where??

Comment: @ManjunathK No I don't think it violates Apple standards.
Actually Apple has a demo of this as well adding this to my answer
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/232/

And please see another great example for getting started with MVVM on iOS (the delegate and data source is the viewController this time):
https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/how-to-use-a-model-view-viewmodel-architecture-for-ios-46963c67be1b

Comment: Thank a lot my friend.. :)

Comment: @ManjunathK Can you please upvote the answer as well? (or is there a reason not to?)